# connect Braintree php sdk with yii

Tags: php, yii, braintree

How can `connect` Braintree php sdk with `yii`.I have placed my  all `sdk`  files in `component` folder and calling `main` file in `controller` like:
include  `Yii::app()->basePath.'/components/braintree/lib/Braintree.php';`

But this shows error to me `include(Braintree_Configuration.php)`: failed to open stream: No such file or `directory`.Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Standard practise to include third party library in Yii (1.x) is to put the code under `protected/vendors` directory, i.e. `protected/vendors/braintree`.

Then include this file in your code like this.

```
Yii::import('application.vendors.*');
require_once('braintree/lib/Braintree.php');
```

Make sure you have provided read permissions for braintree folder.

Comment: I  have placed my files in component if I call my files in same way you said Yii::import('application.component.*');
require_once('braintree/lib/Braintree.php');.it will work?

Comment: It should. Just one correction - it should be `components` not `component`, i.e. plural, in import call.